# SQL запрос по выборке респондентов с дополнительной колонкой подсчета

Tags: mysql, sql, select

прошу помочь с запросом в силу своей неопытности.
Есть 2 таблицы:

```
reg_users:
|  id |  name  |  course  |  
| :-- | ------ | -------: |  
|  1  | Mike   |     2    |  
|  2  | Mike   |     3    |  
|  3  | Sam    |     1    |  
|  4  | Alex   |     1    |
```

Таблица всех зарегистрировавшихся на курсы.

```
course:
|  id   |  name       |
| :---- | ----------: |
|   1   |  photo      |
|   2   |  design     |
|   3   |  floristics |
```

Таблица со списком курсов.

А надо чтобы при выборке помимо замены значения идентификатора названия курса еще в с троке записи указывало сколько человек зарегистрировалось также на этот курс, вот так вот:

```
| id | name | course_name | registered |
| -- | ---- | ----------- | ---------- |
| 1  | Mike | design      | 1          |
| 2  | Mike | floristics  | 1          |
| 3  | Sam  | photo       | 2          |
| 4  | Alex | photo       | 2          |
```

Получается что только Mike записался на два разных курса и напротив его фамилии стоит "1" как у курса "design" так и "floristics", а Sam и Alex записались оба на один курс "photo" из-за чего у обоих цифра "2".

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [join](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html) (вероятно right join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ru.id,ru.name,c.name,total_course_table.total_on_course from reg_users ru  inner 
join course c on (c.id = ru.course) 
inner join (select count(course) as total_on_course ,course from reg_users group by course) total_course_table
on  total_course_table.course = ru.course
```

Возможно не самое оптимальное решение, потому что тут приходится сделать временную таблицу с группированными данными на лету, а это обычно отрицательно влияет на скорость запроса. Поэтому если данных в вашей таблице будет много, возможно имеет смысл предрасчитывать значения записанных, ну или сделаю какую-то другую оптимизаци.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2abf58b/9